# Strategy for making an iPhone Facebook 3.0 like home page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, algorithm

What would be your approach to creating a home page like the new facebook 3.0 app has to offer? There's a grid of 3x3 UIButtons it appears if you look here:

[alt text http://cache0.techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/img_0318.png](http://cache0.techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/img_0318.png)

If you wanted to replicate a similar user interface, would you programmatically have 9 individual buttons that you place on the screen through some kind of loop? If so what would the loop look like?

Would you make one image and hard-code coordinates into an array to see where the user is typing and take an appropriate action?

Comment: Where did this screenshot come from?

Comment: The source to this image is on www.techcrunch.com, search for recent posts about Facebook 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master

Here's the open-source library that Joe Hewitt created in the process of making the iPhone Facebook 3.0 app. This is where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

Joel's pointer to Three20 is the best advice - this is the library that Joe opensourced in the course of creating the Facebook.app.

In terms of how you would generally do it, here's my 2 cents:
You'd have a `UIScrollView` (note that there can be multiple pages of buttons), each hosting a `YourAppButtonGridView`. Each `YourAppButtonGridView` would just have an array of the buttons, and would lay them out in a grid (write this in the `layoutSubviews` method). Bonus points for using `UITabBarItem`, which have a similar look and feel.

Answer (score 1):

For my Application Capsuleer I have a similar "home" screen.

[http://capsuleer.evesuite.com/images/screenshots/mainmenu.jpg http://capsuleer.evesuite.com/images/screenshots/mainmenu.jpg](http://capsuleer.evesuite.com/images/screenshots/mainmenu.jpg)

In my code I built a struct that contained the properties for each button.
Things like:

- Icon image name
- Title
- Pulse state (I use a pulsing background image instead of the badge feature to show somthing has changed)

I then created an array of these structs and initialized them with the details about each button.

My view code then loops over this array and builds the buttons (it sets up all the default properties - background images, fonts, etc.).

I don't currently have multiple pages, but as I expand my application and add more features I'll be filling up the currently unused boxes.  When I get to a point where I have more then fit on one screen, I just switch the backing view from a UIView to a UIScrollView and add a paging control.

All of this is done in code.  I don't use interface builder at all.

It works quite well for my purposes and all I have to change when I add new areas is adjust some lines of code where I initialize my array of structs and the existing code does the rest.

Hope that helps.

chris.

Comment: chris, would you be able to share code that does the physical layout of your buttons in a grid fashion? That would help the most.

Comment: The jist of it is:
http://pastie.org/private/7gw4i2onu3jh3rdxzs9phq

Though there is more to it (I just quickly cut and paste this code out and tryed to simplify it as much as possible - but you get the idea.)

chris.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar.  I created a custom button class and then did this loop

```
for (int i=1;i <= [OGViewControllers numberOfControllers];i++) {

aButton = [[OGMoreButtonView alloc] initWithIcon:[OGViewControllers iconForViewControllerWithIndex:i]
                                        andTitle:[OGViewControllers titleForViewControllerWithIndex:i]];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(((i-1)%4) * 80.0, ((i-1)/4) * 65.0, 80.0, 65.0);
aButton.tag = i;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemSelected:) name:@"AMoreButtonWasTouched" object:aButton];
[self.view addSubview:aButton];
[aButton release];
```

}

If you want the scroll affect with the page indicator throw it all in a scroll view that is 640 wide and turn paging on for the scroll view and set the delegate to self then do something like this

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int oldPage = [pageControl currentPage];

```
[pageControl setCurrentPage:(int)(([scrollView contentOffset].x/320)+0.5)];

if (oldPage != [pageControl currentPage]) [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"OGSwipeViewItemChanged"  object:nil];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the app but from looking at the image i'd say one approach would be to use Interface Builder to lay out 9 custom UIButtons (with your own UIImages in them) in the root view of your Navication Controller and then wire up the IBAction (touch up inside) of each of those to push a new view controller on the stack. Again, I don't use facebook so can't say for sure if that's how it's been wired together.

Answer (score -1):

Start by using interface builder to get everything working. You can get most of the way to it working by just dragging and dropping stuff out of interface builder.

Then later on you can enhance user interface using other drawing techniques.

(NB: This answer was more relevant until the original poster changed their question)

Comment: This adds no real value to the question.